# Allow one controller to work on a different URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have CI structure and a problem in there. Basically what I am trying to achieve is access a controller differently. Except one controller all others are for application internal structure and plays when user is logged. My Controllers for example are: -

1. application/controllers/abc.php
2. application/controllers/xyz.php
3. application/controllers/pqr.php

I want this controller, let's say,  abc.php to be accessible using different URL while xyz, pqr using same way they are right now.

Detailed example with how I have to handle the domain and controller for application.

1. www.domain.com/app
   Here in a folder **app** I have the application which redirects to application's page. While this URL is typed(http://www.domain.com/app), user is redirected to further

www.domain.com/app/controller/method/parameter

For the xyz, pqr controllers I wanted this same route to follow.
www.domain.com/app/xyz/method/parameter 
www.domain.com/app/pqr/method/parameter

2. How I want to access lone abc.php (controller)

www.domain.com/controller/parameter ->
www.domain.com/abc/parameter (note: not like the www.domain.com/app/controller/method/parameter )

while trying to access lone controller like this  http://www.domain.com/controller/parameter I have one more error that I tried to find about but not reached anywhere.

`(Severity: Warning >Message: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Error' does not have a method 'index')` and it's a pain because not much of information I found here.

I hope this time it's better to understand. Apologies. While I was typing it yesterday I had no idea what to type in to give clear idea and as for the code example(it's a simple controller(abc.php) with a model with some functions to fetch data and insert data). It's I guess something I might have to do in routes or .htaccess, however am not sure. So far this is where I reached(Routes/.htaccess). Thank you.

Ah I need atleast 10 reputation to post more than 2 links.

Comment: Some code examples might be useful to clarify what you are trying to do and the issues you are having

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Consider editing your question and adding more details, so that others can help you.

Comment: it is hard to understand your question without some example of the code you're using. Please post some of your code and refer to that when giving examples of what you need to achieve.